# C# P/Invoke: Pointer to string as error message

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, pinvoke, llvm

I am attempting to use llvmc as a C# library using P/Invokes(because I can't find any .NET bindings).

However, I've a problem. llvmc uses char** for error passing.

An example would be this:

```
char* error = NULL;
LLVMVerifyModule(PointerToSomeModule, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
```

What should I do to allow this function to be used in C# code?

EDIT: The [example I found](http://npcontemplation.blogspot.com/2008/06/secret-of-llvm-c-bindings.html) also mentions this call:

```
LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
```

I just saw the answers and thought this could be an important detail.

Comment: I don't have an answer (been a while since I did this, and never with char**), but for future reference this web site has a lot of P/Invoke signatures that can probably help when trying to figure out your own: http://www.pinvoke.net/

Comment: Are your p/invoke efforts for LLVM are made public anywhere?  I found this doing what seems to be a fruitless search for the same.  Thanks!

Comment: @N8allan No, in the end I ended up using System.Reflection.Emit, sorry. The only way to have .NET and LLVM interop right now is via P/Invoke. A while ago there was some talk about .NET/C++ interoperability in some Mono-related project which had the potential to simplify this, but I haven't heard about it in ages, so I assume it probably died.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A char** argument is troublesome, there is a memory management problem.  If you declare the argument as "out string", the P/Invoke marshaller is going to try to free the pointer.  That's very unlikely to work, it requires the string to be allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc().

The only other option you have to declare it as "out IntPtr" and marshal the string yourself with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  That will work, beyond an unpluggable memory leak if LLVMC actually expects you to free the pointer.  Call it a million times to verify that.  There are a few odds that it won't blow since it is an error message, it might return a pointer to a string literal.

The only option left then is to write a wrapper in the C++/CLI language so you can free the pointer.

Comment: What about P/Invoking malloc/calloc and free?

Comment: LLVMDisposeMessage(error) can be used (or so the example I saw says) to dispose the error message.

Comment: Whooptidoo, that's what you need.  Declare the argument as IntPtr on both and use the manual marshaling I recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class. Or you can also simply declare the parameter as an integer out parameter and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi.